# ipad air 2 multitasking replaces the master view on details view

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, multitasking

When I'm doing multitasking and trying to resize the split view after I did a navigation on my master view, then the master view it clones on details view and I can't figure out how to solve it.

[image]

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution applying a method delegate from `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`

```
  func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let primaryNavController = primaryViewController as! UINavigationController
    primaryNavController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)

    let detailNavigationController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavigationController") as! UINavigationController
    let detailViewController = detailNavigationController.viewControllers.first as! DetailViewController

    // Here update your detail view controller

    return detailNavigationController
}
```